# Get safari's search bar to use https?

Tags: https, safari, google-search

In Safari, I have set my homepage to: https://www.google.com
So, when I search from the homepage, my search results route over HTTPS and I also see my +1s

However, if I use the Safari's right-side search bar (which is set to Google),
it does not route my searches over HTTPS. In addition, I do not see my +1s

Comment: Even if you are signed into your Google Account?

Comment: yep! even when I am signed in

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.

I solved this problem by using [SafariOmnibar](https://github.com/rs/SafariOmnibar). By default it also uses http for Google search. But you can edit the search provider plist file to use https instead. The plist file is located at `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/SafariOmnibar.bundle/Contents/Resources/SearchProviders.plist`

Another choice is to use [Glims](https://web.archive.org/web/20190127042610/http://www.machangout.com:80/tutorials/addsearchengine) to add custom search engine. But it maybe overkill to install this plugin just to use https for Google search.